# Getting Exception java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

Java procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_name is

    TYPE REF_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR; 

    PROCEDURE p_fetch_unprocessed_repair (
                IN_OUT_BULK_ID      IN OUT  NUMBER,
                IN_PUBLISH_STATUS   IN  CHAR,
                out_from_date       OUT VARCHAR2,
                out_to_date         OUT VARCHAR2,
                out_repair_info     OUT REF_CURSOR,
                out_error_cd        OUT VARCHAR2
        ) ;

    END;
```

Java code block to invoke stored procedure.

```
try {
    CallableStatement callStatement= conn.prepareCall("{call PKG_NAME.p_fetch_unprocessed_repair(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    callStatement.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD);
    callStatement.setFetchSize(props.getDbBatchSize());
    callStatement.registerOutParameter("IN_OUT_BULK_ID", Types.NUMERIC);
    if(null != bulkID && StringUtils.isNotBlank(bulkStatus)){
        callStatement.setInt("IN_OUT_BULK_ID", bulkID);
    }
    callStatement.setString("IN_PUBLISH_STATUS", bulkStatus);
    callStatement.registerOutParameter("OUT_FROM_DATE", Types.VARCHAR);
    callStatement.registerOutParameter("OUT_TO_DATE", Types.VARCHAR);
    callStatement.registerOutParameter("OUT_REPAIR_INFO", Types.REF);
    callStatement.registerOutParameter("OUT_ERROR_CD", Types.VARCHAR);
    Boolean hadResults = callStatement.execute();
} catch(exception e ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the line

```
            callStatement.registerOutParameter("OUT_REPAIR_INFO", Types.REF);
```

with

```
            callStatement.registerOutParameter("OUT_REPAIR_INFO", oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

Comment: It resolved my issue , but i am not getting any result set eventhogh i hard coded output variable . please help me on this.

Comment: I'm not sure you mean by "not getting any result set".  Do you mean that your variable `hadResults` ends up being `false`?  If that's the case, then ignore that value, and instead try reading the result set out of the callable statement by using a line such as `ResultSet myResultSet = (ResultSet)callStatement.getObject("OUT_REPAIR_INFO");`.